# Change field of other object when this object is saved

Tags: django

I am implementing my own notification system, so for this I have the Notification model:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reciever')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

What I would like is that when this is saved, the unread_notifications boolean on the reciever profile is changed to true.

Profile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    ...
    unread_notifications = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What would be the way to do this? Couldn't find anything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you have a 1-to1 relationship between `User` and `UserProfile`.

You could create a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) for this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Notification(models.Model):
    ...

def update_reciever(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.user.userprofile.unread_notifications = True
        instance.user.userprofile.save()

post_save.connect(update_reciever, sender=Notification)
```

Answer (score 1):

You either use signals as @Gocht answered or override `save` method for your model.

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    # fields

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Notification, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method
        UserProfile.objects.filter(id=self.user.user_profile_id).update(unread_notifications=True)
```

See [overriding model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) for details.